# Unable to change cookie value with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-cookie

I couldn't find an answer on this online so here goes:

I am reading a string from the query string and I am saving it in a cookie using the jquery cookie plugin.

This page may be reloaded a couple of times a day with different ids but it seems to always remember the first value. It seems to be very difficult to get the cookie to change to the new value each time.

```
$.cookie('SomeId')  // already contains some number from the first time the page was called.
```

The logic I am attempting to use is this:

```
if (QueryString.some_id) {
    alert(QueryString.some_id); //shows new Id
    $.cookie('SomeId', null, { expires: -1 }); //Tried deleting old cookie first
    $.cookie('SomeId', QueryString.some_id, { expires: 30, path: '/' }); // Also tried without the path param
    alert($.cookie('SomeId')); // Alerts the OLD id. Previous call didn't work.
}
```

How can I get the `$.cookie('SomeId')` to be updatable?

In case it matters, and I suspect it might, I am running these tests by running the project locally using IIS. It's an MVC application.

Thank you

Comment: Works for me, http://jsfiddle.net/rooseve/5Tp9n/. make sure { path: '/' } is always set.

Comment: What if you first try to remove the cookie like this `$.removeCookie('SomeId');`?

Comment: It works on jFiddle but in my project every time I refresh the page the $.cookie('SomeId') is stuck to the very first value.
Is it maybe failing because the URL is "localhost"?

Comment: I tried with $.removeCookie('SomeId'); and still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue a while back. I fixed it by making up a testing domain [i use clientname.loc and make a new one for each project] and put it in your hosts file [C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts].

```
#existing hosts file entries
127.0.0.1 clientname.loc
```

Alternatively you could use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost as apparently that works to.